# problems sorting a list elements

Tags: python, list, sorting

In Python I found these two pieces of code quite weird:

```
mylist = list (str (2132))
mylist. sort ()
print mylist

>>> ['1','2','3','4']
```

and

```
print (list (str (2132))). sort()

>>> None
```

What is the difference?

It yields None inclusive when I declare a variable like this:

```
mylist = list (str (2132)).sort ()
```

It seems that `sort()` only works in very precise way

Comment: extra note:

I think "print(list(str(2132))).sort()" must be "print(list(str(2132)).sort())" but even so. sort() simply returns None, it changes the existing list but doesn't return it.

Answer (score 2):

In python, [`sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list.sort) is a list method that *sorts a list in-place and returns None*, while [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) returns a sorted copy of a collection without changing the original;

```
>> a = [4,5,3]
>> sorted(a)
[3, 4, 5]

>> a 
[4, 5, 3]

>> a.sort()
>> a
[3, 4, 5]
```